# ASP.NET Core 6 : Swagger does not send/recognize the bearer token

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-6.0, bearer-token, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have bearer token configured in my projects:

- Security API

Nuget packages installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="6.25.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.25.1" />
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
}).AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    // serialize enums as strings in api responses (e.g. Role)
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

    // ignore omitted parameters on models to enable optional params (e.g. User update)
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

// builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWTToken_Auth_API", Version = "v1" });

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 1safsfsdfdfd\"",
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
      {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id = "Bearer"
                                }
            },
        new string[] {}
      }
    });
});

//Add Jwt Token functionality

// Add authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateIssuerSigningKey"]),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:IssuerSigningKey"])),
        ValidateIssuer = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateIssuer"]),
        //ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidAudience"],
        //ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidateAudience = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateAudience"]),
        RequireExpirationTime = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:RequireExpirationTime"]),
        //ValidateLifetime = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateLifetime"])
    };
});

// CORS

builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("cors", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod();
}));
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

AppSettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "JsonWebTokenKeys": {
    "ValidateIssuerSigningKey": true,
    "IssuerSigningKey": "W3YN3-101101-2022",
    "ValidateIssuer": false,
    "ValidIssuer": "https://localhost:7273",
    "ValidateAudience": false,
    "ValidAudience": "https://localhost:7273",
    "RequireExpirationTime": true,
    "ValidateLifetime": true
  }
}
```

Product API

Nuget packages installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="6.25.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.25.1" />
```

ConfigureSwaggerOptions.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace ProductAPI.Extensions
{
    public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
    {
        private readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider;

        public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
        {
            // add swagger document for every API version discovered
            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc(
                    description.GroupName,
                    CreateVersionInfo(description));

                options.AddSecurityDefinition(
                    description.GroupName,
                    CreateSecurityScheme());
                options.AddSecurityRequirement(CreateSecurityRequirement());
            }
        }

        public void Configure(string name, SwaggerGenOptions options)
        {
            Configure(options);
        }

        private OpenApiInfo CreateVersionInfo(ApiVersionDescription description)
        {
            var info = new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "API Products",
                Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString()
            };

            if (description.IsDeprecated)
            {
                info.Description += " This API version has been deprecated.";
            }

            return info;
        }

        private OpenApiSecurityScheme CreateSecurityScheme()
        {
            var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer token\"",
            };
            return securityScheme;
        }

        private OpenApiSecurityRequirement CreateSecurityRequirement()
        {
            var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                        {
                                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, 
                                            Id = "Bearer"}
                                        }, new string[] {}
                        }
                 };

            return securityRequirement;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using ProductAPI.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
    options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true; //deshabilitar validacion automatica
}).AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    // serialize enums as strings in api responses (e.g. Role)
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

    // ignore omitted parameters on models to enable optional params (e.g. User update)
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

// Add Jwt Token functionality

// Add Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateIssuerSigningKey"]),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:IssuerSigningKey"])),
        ValidateIssuer = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateIssuer"]),
        //ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidAudience"],
        //ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidateAudience = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateAudience"]),
        RequireExpirationTime = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:RequireExpirationTime"]),
        ValidateLifetime = bool.Parse(builder.Configuration["JsonWebTokenKeys:ValidateLifetime"])
    };
});

//CORS

builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("cors", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod();

}));

// API Versioning
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(4, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
{
    setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();
var provider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
            description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
        }
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

AppSettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "JsonWebTokenKeys": {
    "ValidateIssuerSigningKey": true,
    "IssuerSigningKey": "W3YN3-101101-2022",
    "ValidateIssuer": false,
    "ValidIssuer": "https://localhost:7273",
    "ValidateAudience": false,
    "ValidAudience": "https://localhost:7273",
    "RequireExpirationTime": true,
    "ValidateLifetime": true
  }
}
```

ProductController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ProductAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("cors")]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[Controller]")]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Product #1", "Product #2", "Product #3"
        };

        [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Ok(Summaries);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use postman the endpoints respond to the tokens I send but when I try to invoke them from the swagger UI the token value is not sent:

[image: endpoint with postman]

[image: endpoint with swaggerUI]

This is the address of my repository:

https://github.com/Weyne/aspnetcore_swagger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CreateSecurityRequirement`, when instantiating `OpenApiSecurityScheme`, you need to provide Id of the version group you were using in `options.SwaggerDoc` and `options.AddSecurityDefinition`:

```
    public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        // add swagger document for every API version discovered
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc(
                description.GroupName,
                CreateVersionInfo(description));

            options.AddSecurityDefinition(
                description.GroupName,
                CreataeSecurityScheme());

            // pass the group name here: 
            options.AddSecurityRequirement(
                CreateSecurityRequirement(description.GroupName));
        }
    }


    private OpenApiSecurityRequirement CreateSecurityRequirement(string groupName)
    {
        var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    // not "Bearer" here, as it was copied form VanillaProject
                        { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = groupName }
                },
                new string[] { }
            }
        };

        return securityRequirement;
    }
```